# Should a theory of quantum gravity be background independent?

Tags: quantum-gravity

If anyone could show some reasoning for and against [background independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_independence) in a general sense that would be great. Also, if there are any mathematical reasons why or why not I'd love to know what they are. I've looked at the wikipedia page but it's all a bit inconclusive.

Comment: This article might be of interest: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0404018

Comment: This should help https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3962